Update ranks according to have many votes a project got (Only Up Votes)
I have this project where I try to rank projects after how many votes they got.
But all the time, the project gets rank 1 no matter vote count.
I build a function to handle rank count and a return handler to update vote count.
Here is the full code:
import clientPromise from '../../mongo/mongoDB';
import { ObjectId } from 'mongodb';

// Import collections and DB name from  configuration
import { collections, DB } from '@/dynamic/mongoDB';

async function calculateRank(userVotesCollection, projectId) {
  const rankData = await userVotesCollection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        project_id: new ObjectId(projectId),
        vote_type: "up"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$project_id",
        totalUpVotes: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        totalUpVotes: -1
      }
    }
  ]).toArray();

  if (rankData.length === 0) {
    return null; // No up-votes for this project
  }

  // Assign ranks based on sorted order
  rankData.forEach((doc, index) => {
    doc.rank = index + 1;
  });

  return rankData[0].rank; // Return rank from the first document (highest up-votes)
}

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { project_id, vote_type, user_address } = req.body;

    try {
      const client = await clientPromise;
      const db = client.db(DB);

      const projectCollection = db.collection(collections.Token);
      const votesCollection = db.collection(collections.userVotes);

      // Validate the project ID
      if (!ObjectId.isValid(project_id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid project ID' });
      }

      // Update the project's vote counts
      let updateFields = {};
      if (vote_type === 'up') {
        updateFields = { $inc: { project_up_votes: 1 } };

        const rank = await calculateRank(votesCollection, project_id);
        if (rank !== null) {
          const updateResult = await projectCollection.updateOne(
            { _id: new ObjectId(project_id) },
            { $set: { project_rank: rank } }
          );
          console.log("Updated rank:", updateResult);
        }
      } else if (vote_type === 'down') {
        updateFields = { $inc: { project_down_votes: 1 } };
      } else if (vote_type === '10-up') {
        updateFields = { $inc: { project_up_votes: 10 } };
      } else if (vote_type === '20-up') {
        updateFields = { $inc: { project_up_votes: 20 } };
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid vote type' });
      }

      const updateResult = await projectCollection.updateOne(
        { _id: new ObjectId(project_id) },
        updateFields
      );

      if (updateResult.modifiedCount === 0) {
        return res.status(404).json({ error: 'Project not found' });
      }

      // Create a new UserVote document object
      const newUserVote = {
        user_address,
        project_id: new ObjectId(project_id),
        vote_type,
      };

      // Save the UserVote document to the votesCollection
      const insertResult = await votesCollection.insertOne(newUserVote);

      if (insertResult.insertedCount !== 1) {
        return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to save vote' });
      }

      // Send a success response to the client
      res.status(200).json({ message: 'Vote cast successfully' });

    } catch (error) {
      // Log any errors that occur and send a 500 error response
      console.error('Cast vote error: ', error);
      res.status(500).json({ error: 'Failed to cast vote' });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    res.status(405).end(`Method ${req.method} Not Allowed`);
  }
}


the higest rank is 1 and lower votes the higher rank number
I tried to count the votes in different ways.

Ensure that the aggregation query correctly computes the total up-votes for each project across all projects.
The current implementation calculates the rank for a single project in isolation, which might be causing incorrect ranking.
Updating the Rank: The update logic should ensure that ranks are recalculated for all projects after each vote.
Let's refactor the calculateRank function to handle ranking for all projects properly

async function calculateRank(userVotesCollection) {
  const rankData = await userVotesCollection.aggregate([
    {
      $match: {
        vote_type: "up"
      }
    },
    {
      $group: {
        _id: "$project_id",
        totalUpVotes: { $sum: 1 }
      }
    },
    {
      $sort: {
        totalUpVotes: -1
      }
    }
  ]).toArray();

  // Assign ranks based on sorted order
  rankData.forEach((doc, index) => {
    doc.rank = index + 1;
  });

  return rankData; // Return the full rank data
}

Modify the handler to update the rank for all projects:

export default async function handler(req, res) {
  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    const { project_id, vote_type, user_address } = req.body;

    try {
      const client = await clientPromise;
      const db = client.db(DB);

      const projectCollection = db.collection(collections.Token);
      const votesCollection = db.collection(collections.userVotes);

      // Validate the project ID
      if (!ObjectId.isValid(project_id)) {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid project ID' });
      }

      // Update the project's vote counts
      let updateFields = {};
      if (vote_type === 'up') {
        updateFields = { $inc: { project_up_votes: 1 } };
      } else if (vote_type === 'down') {
        updateFields = { $inc: { project_down_votes: 1 } };
      } else if (vote_type === '10-up') {
        updateFields = { $inc: { project_up_votes: 10 } };
      } else if (vote_type === '20-up') {
        updateFields = { $inc: { project_up_votes: 20 } };
      } else {
        return res.status(400).json({ error: 'Invalid vote type' });
      }

      const updateResult = await projectCollection.updateOne(
        { _id: new ObjectId(project_id) },
        updateFields
      );

      // Recalculate ranks for all projects
      const rankData = await calculateRank(votesCollection);

      // Update each project's rank in the database
      const bulkOps = rankData.map(doc => ({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { _id: new ObjectId(doc._id) },
          update: { $set: { project_rank: doc.rank } }
        }
      }));

      if (bulkOps.length > 0) {
        await projectCollection.bulkWrite(bulkOps);
      }

      return res.status(200).json({ message: 'Vote registered and ranks updated' });

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error updating vote count:', error);
      return res.status(500).json({ error: 'Internal server error' });
    }
  } else {
    res.setHeader('Allow', ['POST']);
    return res.status(405).json({ error: `Method ${req.method} Not Allowed` });
  }
}

It now calculates the total up-votes for all projects and sorts them.
Ranks are assigned to each project based on the sorted order.
The function returns the rank data for all projects.
Updates the vote count for the given project.
Recalculates ranks for all projects after a vote is cast.
Updates the rank for each project in the database using a bulk write operation.
This approach ensures that the ranks are updated correctly based on the total up-votes for all projects.

It almost works.
When i submit a new project the rank is not getting calculated on vote.
Maybe I insert the rank on submit wrong right now its like this project_rank: Number
I tried it out when i cast a vote for project all ranks got updated. But then i cast vote for one project and its still rank 2 and should be 1 stopped updating the rank

Here the totalUpVotes not getting updated according to database and new projects submitted after your code integration is not getting along with it
[   {     _id: new ObjectId('666c95b70d5f7fe5f79e5a02'),     totalUpVotes: 14,     rank: 1   },   {     _id: new ObjectId('666c95c60d5f7fe5f79e5a03'),     totalUpVotes: 13,     rank: 2   },   {     _id: new ObjectId('666ca1e90d5f7fe5f79e5a1f'),     totalUpVotes: 2,     rank: 3   } ]

This is my Bulk Write
Bulk Write Result: BulkWriteResult {   insertedCount: 0,   matchedCount: 3,   modifiedCount: 0,   deletedCount: 0,   upsertedCount: 0,   upsertedIds: {},   insertedIds: {} }

problem solve you forgot to update user-vote table i added it and now its working perfectly
